# Exchange app permission is removed from Azure Portal

Tags: exchangewebservices, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

As per the MS forum https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/outlook-rest-api-beta-and-outlook-rest-api-v2-0-deprecation/ba-p/1898162, Exchange app permission "full_access_as_app" has been removed from the Azure portal. We are using this permission to access\fetch MSTeams data via Exchange Web Service API. We are planning to switch to Graph API from EWS but on Graph API, the chat list API not being supported, we could not switch to it.

That permission being removed - will it impact our existing app? I mean, our Azure Portal App uses this permission and our customers have already granted the consents so will that change impact our customer? Is there any timeline when that Exchange permission will be deprecated or will stop working? Is there any other alternative to this permission as a workaround?

The main reason for asking this question is: just recently MS has deprecated Basic Authentication to EWS so we switched to Modern Authentication (Oauth 2.0) to connect EWS where we had to use that Exchange app permission "full_access_as_app".

**Now, that permission is not available for the newly created Azure App. Is this a move towards moving away from EWS and switching to Graph API?**

Answer (score 2):

The permissions are still available for new apps (even in the Azure portal if you go though API my organization uses and select "Office365 Exchange Online"). Also in the documentation link in that article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth they give a manual way of doing this through the manifest.

> Now, that permission is not available for the newly created Azure App. Is this a move towards moving away from EWS and switching to Graph API?

Microsoft have been encouraging this move for quite a while (years) but no announcement have been made about the depreciation of EWS and given that for a lot of things (Migrations etc) there is no alternative in the Graph yet it won't be in the near future. And if it does eventually happen you should get at least a year or more notice. That said if you can use the Graph API you should be looking to move to it.